# Angular 2 class doesn´t get recognised

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to use this class:

```
class SortExpression {

    constructor(field, asc) {
        this.field = field;
        this.asc = asc;
    }

    field: string;
    asc: boolean;

    toQueryString() {
        return (this.asc ? '+' : '-') + this.field;
    }
}
```

in my component like that:

```
this.sortFields = new SortExpression('name', true);
```

and i get an `Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: SortExpression is not defined`exception and i really don´t know why. I am pretty new to angular 2 so maybe i am missing something really simple?

Comment: export your class SortExpression, hope this will works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export your class in order to be imported.

```
export class SortExpression {
  ...
}
```

Comment: He also needs to import it.  He must not be or the error would be ok the import statement.